# Parse: Compare PFObject to pointer in class

Tags: ios, pointers, parse-platform, compare, pfobject

I have a PFObject of which one of its sub objects is an array with a pointers to an object of a class (Cars). I want to compare the pointer to an array of PFObjects (Cars) which I have already downloaded previously and find the matching one.

Is there a ways to do this without having to download the pointers class directly? I really want to avoid doing that.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue. Unfortunately parse doesn't allow you to search an array within an object. You have to download the entire array and sift through it manually.